# Only display the largest number in head

Tags: sorting, unix, unix-head

I use sort -r | head and get the out put like this:

```
  8 a1
  8 a2
  5 a3
  5 a4
  4 a5
  4 a6
  4 a7
  4 a8
  4 a9
  4 a0
```

What can I do to make the output like this:

```
  8 a1
  8 a2
```

only the largest k1 number show up????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, but here is one using `awk`.  Since it is already sorted, you want to check to just print lines that match the first value by piping the `head`ed list into something like

```
awk 'BEGIN{maxval=0}; (maxval==0) {maxval=$1}; ($1==maxval) {print $0}'
```